# Attach pdf with Email Copy of shipment

Tags: pdf, attachment

I want a pdf to be attached with the mail which is sent when I ship my order and tick the option 'Email Copy of shipment'.
pdf should contain same content as mail, as only those items list from the order which i had shipped not all items.
I know how to attach files with the mail, but what I want to know is how to generate pdf each time and attach with the mail or any other simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have this code that works good **app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Shipment.php** for sending e-mail to customer with attached invoice when order status changes to "Shipped" :

```
 `if (strpos($template, 'shipped')){
  $id_factura = $templateVars['{id_order}'];
   $orden = new Order($id_factura);
  $factura['content'] = PDF::invoice($orden, 'S');
   $factura['name'] = $id_factura.'.pdf';
   $factura['mime'] = 'application/pdf';
   $message->attach(new Swift_Message_Attachment($factura['content'], $factura['name'], $factura['mime']));
}`
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to use the above code, I am new to magento, cant decide where to place the code in Shipment.php